# No screenshots after asking for it, added them myself, dropping the comment. Edit rejected: "This edit ... should have been written as a comment ...."

Tags: discussion, specific-question, suggested-edits, reject

Edit rejected:

> This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.

https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1126302

I commented below a day before changing that answer, asking for more steps and screenshots. The user added the steps, but not the screenshots. Since I think that screenshots gain a lot in any answer, I added those screenshots myself and deleted my meta noise comment that was asking for more.

I added more information as well, for example that quoting `"my_shortcut"` will lead to those commands that have only this keybinding. I also checked the grammar since I was there. Still, the reason to change anything at all were the missing screenshots that I had asked for in a comment which I had at hand since I followed the steps that were written in that answer.

The edit was rejected since I should have commented instead. I did comment, I just deleted it. Another change by the user was nothing you would expect. If an answer does not get any screenshots when asked for in the comment, then I see a reason why I should edit the answer.

Is this a misunderstanding? Would the edit have worked if I had left my comment? I guess not, so that even then, my edit would likely have been rejected. I just do not think it is a good thing to push down anyone who likes to add screenshots. This should be taken into account clearer by the edit reviewers.

Comment: I've approved the edit for you.

Comment: @DavidPostill That is now hopefully a gain for both questions. :)